# Enable Voice / Speech input BotFramework V4 Emulator

Tags: botframework, speech-recognition, cortana

I've just started to develop skills for `cortana`. If I test my Bot on `Azure` in the integrated Online-Test, I am able to communicate with the bot via voice or text. But if I test my bot with `Bot Framework Emulator V4`, I am not able to communicate with the bot via voice, only via text.

I hope it is a simple question for you! I don't have an idea why.

So, what do think is the problem? What kind of information do you need to help?

Answer (score 2):

The emulator is a smarter version of webchat. It doesn't emulate cortana channel. Also, bot service examples by default do not add speech to the bots.  You need to add .speak to the message in appropriate places, or use .say instead of .send.

The easiest thing to do is develop your bot as if it were text only. Once it works locally using emulator, then add speech and using Ngrok set the cortana (bot service) endpoint to your local endpoint.  When you have speech built the way you want, then deploy to the cloud.

Personally, I do 99% of what I need in the cloud using azure portal and console.  I don't use the emulator.  Check out

- http://www.octavianit.com/2018/07/end-to-end-developer-example-video-of.html (echo bot modified to work with Cortana)
- http://www.octavianit.com/2018/07/get-your-azue-qna-bot-to-speak-with.html (qna maker modified to work with Cortana)